# How to pass database query in Angular Get API URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular8

I have below function in my service file which i am executing from Component, i want to prepare one get URL from below function.

```
getStartEndTime(body) {
    const query = `select min(shiftstart) starttimeofmonth,max(shiftend) endtimeofmonth from ShiftCalendarDeDup where lineid=${body.lineId} and factoryid=${body.factoryId} and businessdate between ${body.firstDay} and ${body.lastDay}`;
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiDFOS3BaseUrl}/dfosbroker/generic/query/${query}`);
  
  }
```

But above code generates below URL in the Network tab

**URL :**

```
https://dfos-qa.unilever.com/dfosbroker/generic/query/select%20min(shiftstart)%20starttimeofmonth,max(shiftend)%20endtimeofmonth%20from%20ShiftCalendarDeDup%20where%20lineid=E_A571_A%20and%20factoryid=E_A571%20and%20businessdate%20between%202023-10-01%20and%202023-10-31
```

**My expected output**

```
https://dfos.unilever.com/dfosbroker/generic/query/select min(shiftstart) starttimeofmonth,max(shiftend) endtimeofmonth from ShiftCalendarDeDup where lineid='R_A002_MAFLRIA1' and factoryid='R_A002' and businessdate between '2023-10-01' and '2023-10-31'
```

Can anyone help me to get my expected output.

Comment: Yes, it is just wrong to build such DB queries from UI. They should be made on the server side.

Comment: Not possible, URL need to be URL-encoded, that's why you will see some characters such as space, single code were converted to encoded character. In your server side, you should extract the value from query string and decode to get the original value before encoded. Otherwise, you should implement the API as POST and receive the query in the request body. So you don't need to encode the value. Meanwhile, a high concern that your API should have some mechanisms to prevent SQL injection. Otherwise, you may face the issue that the API is misused, data exposed and the table, database dropped.

Comment: And of course with your current implementation, people already know the table and columns available in your database.

Comment: frontend shouldn't know about backend! You can attach query params e.g. someUrl/?minbusinessdate="2023-11-11" via https://angular.dev/guide/http/making-requests#setting-url-parameters. The backend should parse the query params and take care of implementation i.e the actual database queries.